# Conditional Execution of Test Cases in TestNG

Tags: java, automation, annotations, testng, appium

I'm using appium to perform tests on mobile applications. What I'm trying to do is only execute the test cases written in Class 1 if the value of "numberOfAssets" is 1. And then ONLY execute test cases written in class 2 if "numberOfAssets" is 2.
I have been trying to find a fix for this and stumbled upon the "Annotation Transformer" class. But the sad part is that it ends up setting ALL the "@Test" annotations to true.

All i want is for only one whole class to execute based on the "numberOfAssets" value. I would appreciate some suggestions regarding this.

I have three classes-

initialSetUp class-

```
public class initialSetUp{
    AndroidDriver driver;
    int numberOfAssets = 1;
@BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "4.4.2"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");           
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.temp.app_name");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.temp.app_name.start_activity"); 
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown(){
        //close the app
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Class 1-

```
    @Listeners(AnnotationTransformer.class)
    @Test(enabled = false, groups = "yo")
    public class oneAssetType extends initialSetUp{
    //Check if first page is asset type specified
//  @Test (groups = "onlyOne", priority = 1)
    public void test_1() throws Exception {
        WebElement centerLable = driver.findElement(By.id("pagerTitle"));
        assert centerLable.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Whatever") :  "did not match with expected value";
    }
}
```

Class 2-

```
@Test(enabled = false)
    public class twoAssetType extends initialSetUp{
        //Check if first page is stickers
        @Test (groups = {"twoAssets", "a"}, priority = 1) 
        public void test_1() throws Exception {
            WebElement centerLable = driver.findElement(By.id("pagerTitle"));
            assert centerLable.getText().equals("WhereEver") : "did not match with expected value";
            }
    }
```

TestNG.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Main App Suite">
   <listeners>
        <listener class-name="package_name.AnnotationTransformer" />
    </listeners>

   <test name="Navigate one Asset Types">
      <classes>
        <class name="package_name.oneAssetType" />
      </classes>
   </test> 

 <test name="Navigate two asset types">
       <classes>
           <class name="package_name.twoAssetType" />
       </classes>
   </test>   
</suite>
```

I have also setup a annotation transformer class-

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    initialSetUp setup = new initialSetUp();
    @Override
    public void transform (ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod){        
        try{
            if (testClass.getName().equals("package_name.oneAssetType") && (setup.numberOfAssets == 1)) {
                annotation.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            //YO
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information, `@Listeners(AnnotationTransformer.class)` is not working. [The documentation says](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners):

> The @Listeners annotation can contain any class that extends
>   org.testng.ITestNGListener except IAnnotationTransformer and
>   IAnnotationTransformer2. The reason is that these listeners need to be
>   known very early in the process so that TestNG can use them to rewrite
>   your annotations, therefore you need to specify these listeners in
>   your testng.xml file.

Then, about the problem you have, your `initialSetUp` instance from listener is not the test itself. So, `setup.numberOfAssets` will never change. Annotation transformers are used before the run of the test and without runtime context.
Instead, you can try something with [IHookable](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#ihookable).